# What does a hosting environment mean in a web server?

Tags: hosting

I came across the term hosting environment while i am going through the concept of ASP .Net lifecycle. Can anyone explain me in detail regarding this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

**Hosting Environment Creation and Responsibilities**

An instance of the HostingEnvironment will be created within the ApplicationDomain prior to ASP's creation and initialization of the HttpRuntime and all of the other associated core objects.

The HostingEnvironment contains details specific to the Application itself, such as where the Application is stored at and functions and services essential to managing the entire application.

**HttpRuntime Creation and Responsibilities**

The HttpRuntime (and several other core objects) will not be created until after the HostingEnvironment and ApplicationDomain have been created.

The HttpRuntime class is responsible for handling functions and services related to handling all of the HTTP Requests and Responses that are performed within the application. It also features some functions to access information regarding the domain of the current application.

**Quick Summaries**

- The HostingEnvironment is responsible for handling application-specific functions and application management and is created before the HttpRuntime (HttpRuntime CANNOT be created until after the ApplicationDomain and HostingEnvironment have been created.)
- The HttpRuntime (and its related objects) is responsible for handling run-time operations within the application but not application-specific management operations. (It will NOT be created until after the HostingEnvironment has been created)

Answer (score 0):

This is simply a ready to use environment provided by many vendors on a monthly or annual fee or may be setup by yourself to host or deploy your software there.

You can read more [on wiki here about hosting environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosting_environment)

or just google for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Hosting environment can be a reference to the hardware\software\location\configuration used to host software.

In terms of ASP.NET it most likely means:

- Using IIS or IIS Express
- What version of the .NET framework
- What Operating system

Depending on the context it can also mean what hosting environment meaning third party service provider will host your web application such as Go Daddy or Rack Space.

Comment: Step 2: If this is the first request to the website, then a class called as ‘ApplicationManager’ creates an application domain where the website can run. As we all know, the application domain creates isolation between two web applications hosted on the same IIS.

Step 3: The newly created application domain creates hosting environment, i.e. the ‘HttpRuntime’ object. Once the hosting environment is created, the necessary core ASP.NET objects like ‘HttpContext’ , ‘HttpRequest’ and ‘HttpResponse’ objects are created.

Comment: In the comment i have added above please take a look at HttpRuntime object. Why are they callin this an hosting environment? My Question may sound silly, but your comments will be of much help

Answer (score 0):

A environment is a Server in which it lives. A server hosting environment is a stand alone hosting cluster of servers in which are able to handle  multiple websites for Web Hosting.